# .NET Core 2 - Create instance of controller class which has a repository

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following controller Class;

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private IValueService _service;

    public MyController(IValueService service)
    {
        this._service = service;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var values = _service.GetAll();
    }
}
```

I would like to create an instance of this Class and call the method MyMethod(), e.g.

```
var MyCopy = new MyController();
MyCopy.MyMethod();
```

However i get the message i need to give the required service parameter. How would i create an instance of a controller that has a service (repository) so i can call its methods?

Comment: Controller is a normal class, the same as any other class. You must supply a value for service parameter like `var myservice = new ValueService(); var mycopy = new MyController(myservice);`

Comment: No, no, no, you don't ever need to instantiate your own controllers, let the MVC framework do that for you. If you need to call a method, that method should be in it's own, non-controller class, preferably injected with the built in DI container.

Comment: What dependency does your `IValueService` implementation have that prevents you from calling `service.GetAll()` directly?

Comment: IValueSerive uses DataContext : DbContext

Comment: @DavidG - could you provide an example how to use the DI container with this class / method - could be the answer i am looking for (removing the controller bit)

Comment: This is just normal DI and normal object-oriented programming. Plenty of tutorials online, go look 'em up :)

Comment: Then instantiate the DbContext. `IValueService service = new ValueService(new DataContext(options))`. Provide options as required by your application.

Comment: Check out the [dependency injection topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) in the documentation. – *Why* do you want to do this in the first place? Is this for unit testing?

Comment: @poke - Well, on startup I would like to run a method in a class that uses a repository. This method first opens a SocketIO connection and then it should use the repository to save new incoming data to the database. New to a lot of concepts, so a bit lost what the correct structure would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Well, on startup I would like to run a method in a class that uses a repository. This method first opens a SocketIO connection and then it should use the repository to save new incoming data to the database.

Then that logic shouldn’t be inside a controller but in some service type instead which you register with the dependency injection container. Controllers are to respond to requests at certain routes, but your thing sounds like it’s a general initialization step in your application that runs outside of a request. So there should be no controller involved.

Instead, you want to make some service first:

```
public class MyInitializationService
{
    private readonly IValueService _valueService;

    public MyInitializationService(IValueService valueService)
    {
        _valueService = valueService;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        var values = _valueService.GetAll();
        // do something
    }
}
```

You then register that class in the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup` class:

```
services.AddTransient<MyInitializationService>();
```

And then, you can inject that type into the `Configure` method and call its `Initialize` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, MyInitializationService initializationService)
{
    initializationService.Initialize();

    // …
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

There are various ways of running something at the beginning when an application starts. Calling it inside `Configure` is just one way, which may or may not be appropriate depending on how early you want your code to run (since `Configure` runs very early). Another good way would be to register a callback to the [`ApplicationStarted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime.applicationstarted) event of the application lifetime. I have an [answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178087/216074) which goes into more details on that.

Answer (score 14):

In Startup file add :

```
 services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
```

it will registers all controllers in your application with the DI container.

Then :

```
   var serviceProvider = HttpContext.RequestServices;
     var controller =(MyController)serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyController>();
     controller.Method();
```

Comment: this works, but the controller lacks the HttpContext, is there any way we can pass it?

Comment: I have the issue with null HttpContext as well, is there some way to properly initialise this?