# .NET Core 2 - Call Repository method from Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following Repository and Class;

```
public interface IValueService
{
    GetAll();
}

public class ValueService : IValueService
{
    private DataContext _context;

    public ValueService(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;            
    }

    public GetAll()
    {
       // do something
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs;

```
services.AddScoped<IValueService, ValueService>();
```

How would i call the method GetAll() from Startup or from another Class?

EDIT: Answered in; [.NET Core 2 - Create instance of controller class which has a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633396/net-core-2-create-instance-of-controller-class-which-has-a-repository/48633924#48633924)

Comment: from another class ? Inject `IValueService` via constructor injection and use that. Take a look at [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection)

Comment: This is basially the same question you aked a few minutes ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633396/net-core-2-create-instance-of-controller-class-which-has-a-repository

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this question to receive down votes. If so, please share your critic so the author can improve the question.

Comment: @DavidG yes, still the same problem - would be great if could point me in the right direction. To my understanding a controller gets called from the front-end. However, i just need to know how to call these methods without using a controller / front-end.

Comment: You've already been given a few links, it's now up to you to go and learn.

Comment: @phicon, you don't have to use controller to call a service. Service A could call Service B as well. Just follow the link I put in my answer and you will learn that.

Answer (score 3):

To call `GetAll()`, you need to have an instance first, no matter where. So if you want to call it in the `Startup.cs`, you have to create an object first and then call it.

For other class to call the `GetAll()`, you need to specify `IValueService` as one of constructor's parameter, then in the constructor, you keep the `IValueService` instance in a local private property. This private property could be used in the other methods in the same class.

For .NetCore 2 dependency injection, click the [MSDN Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Could be this article can help: https://medium.com/@mattmazzola/asp-net-core-injecting-custom-data-classes-into-startup-classs-constructor-and-configure-method-7cc146f00afb

Basically to inject some service to the startup, you need to call `ConfigureServices` before calling `UseStartup` in `WebHostBuilder()` chain:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.ConfigureServices(servicesCollection =>
{
    servicesCollection.AddSingleton<IValueService>(new ValueService(context));
})
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();
```

Then your service would be resolved if injected to startup constructor:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env, IValueService service)
        {
           //service.GetAll();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller or class you want to use add the following code:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IValueService _valueServiceRepository;

    public MyController (IValueService _valueServiceRepository)
    {
        _valueServiceRepository = valueServiceRepository;
    }

}
```

Now you can use _valueServiceRepository.GetAll().